# Javascript load Image into Offscreen Canvas, perform webp conversion

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, webp

I recently used canvas to conert images to webp, using :

const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');

But this takes a lots of time for certain images, like 400ms.

I got a warning from Chrome, since it is blocking UI.

I would like to use an Offscreen Canvas to perform that conversion in background.

But :

1) I don't know which Offscreen Canvas I should use :
   a] new OffscreenCanvas()
   b] canvas.transferControlToOffscreen()

2) I load a local image url in an Image object (img.src = url) to get width and height of the local image. But I don't understand how to transfert the Image object to the offscreen Canvas, to be able to do in the worker :

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)

Because If I don't transfert the image, worker doesn't know img.

Comment: use a placeholder `img` before and then set `img.src = url` using javascript, also attach a onload function on the `img` and render when the img gets loaded

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are facing an [XY and even -Z problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here, but each may have an useful answer, so let's dig in.

---

**X**. **Do not use the canvas API to perform image format conversion**. 
The canvas API is lossy, whatever you do, you will loose information from your original image, even if you do pass it lossless images, the image drawn on the canvas will not be the same as this original image.
If you pass an already lossy format like JPEG, it will even add information that were not in the original image: the compression artifacts are now part of the raw bitmap, and export algo will treat these as information it should keep, making your file probably bigger than the JPEG file you fed it with.

Not knowing your use case, it's a bit hard to give you the perfect advice, but generally, make the different formats from the version the closest to the raw image, and once it's painted in a browser, you are already at least three steps too late.

---

Now, if you do some processing on this image, you may indeed want to export the results.
But you probably don't need this Web Worker here.
**Y**. What takes the biggest blocking time in your description should be the synchronous [`toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) call.
Instead of this historical error in the API, you should always be using the asynchronous and nonetheless more performant [`toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method. In 99% of the cases, you don't need a data URL anyway, almost all you want to do with a data URL should be done with a Blob directly.

Using this method, the only heavy synchronous operation remaining would be the painting on canvas, and unless you are downsizing some huge images, this should not take the 400ms.

But you can anyway make it even better on newest canvas thanks to [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) method, which allows you to prepare asynchronously your image so that the image's decoding be complete and all that needs to be done is really just a *put pixels* operation:

```js
large.onclick = e => process('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/Black_hole_-_Messier_87.jpg');
medium.onclick = e => process('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Black_hole_-_Messier_87.jpg/1280px-Black_hole_-_Messier_87.jpg');

function process(url) {
  convertToWebp(url)
    .then(prepareDownload)
    .catch(console.error);
}

async function convertToWebp(url) {
  if(!supportWebpExport())
  console.warn("your browser doesn't support webp export, will default to png");

  let img = await loadImage(url);
  if(typeof window.createImageBitmap === 'function') {
    img = await createImageBitmap(img);
  }
  const ctx = get2DContext(img.width, img.height);

  console.time('only sync part');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
  console.timeEnd('only sync part');
  
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    ctx.canvas.toBlob( blob => {
      if(!blob) rej(ctx.canvas);
      res(blob);
    }, 'image/webp');
  });
}

// some helpers

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = e => res(img);
    img.onerror = rej;
  });
}

function get2DContext(width = 300, height=150) {
  return Object.assign(
    document.createElement('canvas'),
    {width, height}
  ).getContext('2d');
}

function prepareDownload(blob) {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = 'image.' + blob.type.replace('image/', '');
  a.textContent = 'download';
  document.body.append(a);
}

function supportWebpExport() {
  return get2DContext(1,1).canvas
    .toDataURL('image/webp')
    .indexOf('image/webp') > -1;
}
```

```html
<button id="large">convert large image (7,416 × 4,320 pixels)</button>
<button id="medium">convert medium image (1,280 × 746 pixels)</button>
```

---

**Z**. To draw an image on an OffscreenCanvas from a Web Worker, you will need the `createImageBitmap` mentioned above. Indeed, the ImageBitmap object produced by this method is the only *image source* value that [drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and [texImage2D()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D)(*) can accept which is available in Workers (all other being DOM Elements).

This ImageBitmap is [transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable), so you could generate it from the main thread and then send it to you Worker with no memory cost:

**main.js**

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = e => {
  createImageBitmap(img).then(bmp => {
    // transfer it to your worker
    worker.postMessage({
      image: bmp // the key to retrieve it in `event.data`
    },
   [bmp] // transfer it
  );
};
img.src = url;
```

An other solution is to fetch your image's data from the Worker directly, and to generate the ImageBitmap object from the fetched Blob:

**worker.js**

```
const blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
const img = await createImageBitmap(blob);
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

---

And note if you got the original image in your main's page as a Blob (e.g from an <input type="file">), then don't even go the way of the HTMLImageElement, nor of the fetching, directly send this Blob and generate the ImageBitmap from it.

*<sup>*texImage2D* actually accepts more source image formats, such as TypedArrays, and ImageData objects, but these TypedArrays should represent the pixel data, just like an ImageData does, and in order to have this pixel data, you probably need to already have drawn the image somewhere using one of the other *image source* formats.</sup>

Comment: With your insights, I was able to produce the solution I expedted. Thanks !